# unable to generate video output in heroku

Tags: python, opencv, flask, heroku, face-detection

I made this simple face detection and tracking app using flask, opencv and mediapipe. This works completely fine on my local host but when i deployed it on Heroku the the app is unable to show results . Can someone please tell me what's the issue here ?
Deployment - http://face1-detection.herokuapp.com/

app.py:

```
import base64
import cv2
import io

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from engineio.payload import Payload
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import mediapipe as mp

Payload.max_decode_packets = 2048

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


def readb64(base64_string):
    idx = base64_string.find('base64,')
    base64_string = base64_string[idx + 7:]

    sbuf = io.BytesIO()

    sbuf.write(base64.b64decode(base64_string, ' /'))
    pimg = Image.open(sbuf)

    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pimg), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)



@socketio.on('catch-frame')
def catch_frame(data):
    emit('response_back', data)



@socketio.on('image')
def image(data_image):
    frame = (readb64(data_image))
    frame = face_detector(frame)

    imgencode = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', frame, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 40])[1]

    # base64 encode
    stringData = base64.b64encode(imgencode).decode('utf-8')
    b64_src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'
    stringData = b64_src + stringData

    # emit the frame back
    emit('response_back', stringData)


def face_detector(img):
    mpFaceDetection = mp.solutions.face_detection
    faceDetection = mpFaceDetection.FaceDetection()

    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    results = faceDetection.process(img)
    if results.detections:
        for id, detection in enumerate(results.detections):
            if detection.score[0] > 0.50:
                bboxc = detection.location_data.relative_bounding_box
                ih, iw, ic = img.shape
                bbox = int(bboxc.xmin * iw), int(bboxc.ymin * ih), int(bboxc.width * iw), int(bboxc.height * ih)
                cv2.rectangle(img, bbox, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2.putText(img, f"{int(detection.score[0] * 100)}%",
                            (int(bboxc.xmin * iw), int(bboxc.ymin * ih - 15)),
                            cv2.FONT_ITALIC, 1.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return img


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, port=9990, debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Face Detection/Tracking</title>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.0/socket.io.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
    <video autoplay playsinline id="videoElement"></video>
    <canvas id="canvas"  width="400" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div class = 'video'>
        <img id="photo"  width="400"  height="300">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var socket = io.connect(window.location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
        socket.on('connect', function(){
            console.log("Connected...!", socket.connected)
        });


        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

        video.width = 400;
        video.height = 300;


        if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
            .then(function (stream) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();
            })
            .catch(function (err0r) {

            });
        }

        const FPS = 10;
        setInterval(() => {
            width=video.width;
            height=video.height;
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width , height );
            var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, width,height );
            socket.emit('image', data);
        }, 1000/FPS);

        socket.on('response_back', function(image){
                photo.setAttribute('src', image );

        });

    </script>


 </body>

</html>
```

This is the literally the entrie code . If anyone know what's the issue please let me know

heroku logs :

```
2022-02-24T12:25:42.965622+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
2022-02-24T12:25:42.965975+00:00 app[web.1]: self.run()
2022-02-24T12:25:42.965978+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
2022-02-24T12:25:42.966270+00:00 app[web.1]: self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
2022-02-24T12:25:42.966271+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 682, in _handle_event_internal
2022-02-24T12:25:42.966505+00:00 app[web.1]: r = server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])
2022-02-24T12:25:42.966508+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 711, in _trigger_event
2022-02-24T12:25:42.966760+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
2022-02-24T12:25:42.966762+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 282, in _handler
2022-02-24T12:25:42.966976+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._handle_event(handler, message, namespace, sid,
2022-02-24T12:25:42.966988+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 713, in _handle_event
2022-02-24T12:25:42.967281+00:00 app[web.1]: ret = handler(*args)
2022-02-24T12:25:42.967283+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 45, in image
2022-02-24T12:25:42.967418+00:00 app[web.1]: frame = face_detector(frame)
2022-02-24T12:25:42.967421+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 75, in face_detector
2022-02-24T12:25:42.967505+00:00 app[web.1]: cv2.waitKey(0)
2022-02-24T12:25:42.967534+00:00 app[web.1]: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1334: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvWaitKey'
2022-02-24T12:25:42.967534+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-24T12:26:09.779758+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiQuB&sid=29235acf6cbb4841a384245766e80a2b" host=newfacetrack.herokuapp.com request_id=d61b9d83-a0e0-4eb0-9d24-dfe323cc4edd fwd="27.57.153.242" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-02-24T12:26:10.655608+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:10 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:186)
2022-02-24T12:26:10.656419+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:10 +0000] [186] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 186)
2022-02-24T12:26:11.666532+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:11 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 186 was terminated due to signal 9
2022-02-24T12:26:11.669039+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:11 +0000] [234] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 234
2022-02-24T12:26:13.042608+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.86.207 - - [24/Feb/2022:12:26:13 +0000] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiRpq&sid=9cc0990633a541dc87c57595bfb13d16 HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "https://newfacetrack.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"
2022-02-24T12:26:13.042740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiQuB&sid=29235acf6cbb4841a384245766e80a2b" host=newfacetrack.herokuapp.com request_id=64b4b546-f9ce-453a-8066-104dc6255af5 fwd="27.57.153.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2290ms status=400 bytes=217 protocol=https
2022-02-24T12:26:13.043767+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.61.212 - - [24/Feb/2022:12:26:13 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiQuB&sid=29235acf6cbb4841a384245766e80a2b HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "https://newfacetrack.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"
2022-02-24T12:26:13.043901+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiRpq&sid=9cc0990633a541dc87c57595bfb13d16" host=newfacetrack.herokuapp.com request_id=0bcad996-a7c6-46f0-8c10-8ceb1b47cfea fwd="27.57.153.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=29783ms status=400 bytes=282 protocol=https
2022-02-24T12:26:13.232505+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiReF&sid=9cc0990633a541dc87c57595bfb13d16" host=newfacetrack.herokuapp.com request_id=432efae7-3f32-4fc2-9afa-41ebf72254e3 fwd="27.57.153.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-02-24T12:26:13.429670+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiZBQ&sid=9cc0990633a541dc87c57595bfb13d16" host=newfacetrack.herokuapp.com request_id=e50fa29c-b6f2-4e69-9c25-4272b6a9ca3d fwd="27.57.153.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=400 bytes=282 protocol=https
2022-02-24T12:26:13.430897+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.61.212 - - [24/Feb/2022:12:26:13 +0000] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiZBQ&sid=9cc0990633a541dc87c57595bfb13d16 HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "https://newfacetrack.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"
2022-02-24T12:26:13.696329+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:13 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:194)
2022-02-24T12:26:13.697959+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:13 +0000] [194] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 194)
2022-02-24T12:26:14.707233+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:14 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 194 was terminated due to signal 9
2022-02-24T12:26:14.710332+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:14 +0000] [242] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 242
2022-02-24T12:26:15.048217+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiZah" host=newfacetrack.herokuapp.com request_id=e617be25-8fb5-4955-8d1a-f55828face7a fwd="27.57.153.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=390 protocol=https
2022-02-24T12:26:15.049518+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.61.212 - - [24/Feb/2022:12:26:15 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiZah HTTP/1.1" 200 107 "https://newfacetrack.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"
2022-02-24T12:26:15.764956+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiZfu&sid=fe6ff1caa2e94b669a5ec16e1b3b560f" host=newfacetrack.herokuapp.com request_id=5f5ddd22-675e-40c9-9725-46a5a174d20a fwd="27.57.153.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=386ms status=200 bytes=264 protocol=https
2022-02-24T12:26:15.766176+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.61.212 - - [24/Feb/2022:12:26:15 +0000] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiZfu&sid=fe6ff1caa2e94b669a5ec16e1b3b560f HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "https://newfacetrack.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"
2022-02-24T12:26:15.819042+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
2022-02-24T12:26:15.843333+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread Thread-2:
2022-02-24T12:26:15.843349+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-02-24T12:26:15.843365+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
2022-02-24T12:26:15.843762+00:00 app[web.1]: self.run()
2022-02-24T12:26:15.843777+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
2022-02-24T12:26:15.844159+00:00 app[web.1]: self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
2022-02-24T12:26:15.844179+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 682, in _handle_event_internal
2022-02-24T12:26:15.844630+00:00 app[web.1]: r = server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])
2022-02-24T12:26:15.844744+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 711, in _trigger_event
2022-02-24T12:26:15.845771+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
2022-02-24T12:26:15.845792+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 282, in _handler
2022-02-24T12:26:15.846006+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._handle_event(handler, message, namespace, sid,
2022-02-24T12:26:15.846020+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 713, in _handle_event
2022-02-24T12:26:15.846336+00:00 app[web.1]: ret = handler(*args)
2022-02-24T12:26:15.846350+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 45, in image
2022-02-24T12:26:15.846458+00:00 app[web.1]: frame = face_detector(frame)
2022-02-24T12:26:15.846483+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 75, in face_detector
2022-02-24T12:26:15.846678+00:00 app[web.1]: cv2.waitKey(0)
2022-02-24T12:26:15.846748+00:00 app[web.1]: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1334: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvWaitKey'
2022-02-24T12:26:15.846760+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-24T12:26:16.866520+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiZsa&sid=fe6ff1caa2e94b669a5ec16e1b3b560f" host=newfacetrack.herokuapp.com request_id=6a81ebf1-8ab9-4a1e-96f3-537d564c3a59 fwd="27.57.153.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=676ms status=400 bytes=282 protocol=https
2022-02-24T12:26:16.867623+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.61.212 - - [24/Feb/2022:12:26:16 +0000] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiZsa&sid=fe6ff1caa2e94b669a5ec16e1b3b560f HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "https://newfacetrack.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"
2022-02-24T12:26:17.334909+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Nyhia8Q&sid=fe6ff1caa2e94b669a5ec16e1b3b560f" host=newfacetrack.herokuapp.com request_id=9a67de4f-58e2-4919-a636-1ac3bf0d6ce7 fwd="27.57.153.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=400 bytes=282 protocol=https
2022-02-24T12:26:17.336190+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.61.212 - - [24/Feb/2022:12:26:17 +0000] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Nyhia8Q&sid=fe6ff1caa2e94b669a5ec16e1b3b560f HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "https://newfacetrack.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"
2022-02-24T12:26:19.037947+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiaZ4" host=newfacetrack.herokuapp.com request_id=57087b58-ce3a-4422-a17e-54751a6a665c fwd="27.57.153.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=390 protocol=https
2022-02-24T12:26:19.039249+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.61.212 - - [24/Feb/2022:12:26:19 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiaZ4 HTTP/1.1" 200 107 "https://newfacetrack.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"
2022-02-24T12:26:19.377341+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiaeH&sid=987213a56f574506a7fe38ec6a023e81" host=newfacetrack.herokuapp.com request_id=e5fbacaf-fd00-4b7e-9c45-5cb1fbe5d3c5 fwd="27.57.153.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=264 protocol=https
2022-02-24T12:26:19.378487+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.61.212 - - [24/Feb/2022:12:26:19 +0000] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiaeH&sid=987213a56f574506a7fe38ec6a023e81 HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "https://newfacetrack.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"
2022-02-24T12:26:19.990013+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
2022-02-24T12:26:20.005617+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread Thread-2:
2022-02-24T12:26:20.005620+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-02-24T12:26:20.005640+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006002+00:00 app[web.1]: self.run()
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006003+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006246+00:00 app[web.1]: self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006249+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 682, in _handle_event_internal
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006393+00:00 app[web.1]: r = server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006395+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 711, in _trigger_event
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006535+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006546+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 282, in _handler
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006625+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._handle_event(handler, message, namespace, sid,
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006627+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 713, in _handle_event
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006775+00:00 app[web.1]: ret = handler(*args)
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006776+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 45, in image
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006819+00:00 app[web.1]: frame = face_detector(frame)
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006821+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 75, in face_detector
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006872+00:00 app[web.1]: cv2.waitKey(0)
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006909+00:00 app[web.1]: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1334: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvWaitKey'
2022-02-24T12:26:20.006910+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-24T12:26:45.394033+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiZfw&sid=fe6ff1caa2e94b669a5ec16e1b3b560f" host=newfacetrack.herokuapp.com request_id=c6c1e0b6-c6d6-4ad0-af76-43362b45e9fc fwd="27.57.153.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-02-24T12:26:45.997770+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:45 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:234)
2022-02-24T12:26:45.998218+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:45 +0000] [234] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 234)
2022-02-24T12:26:47.007109+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:47 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 234 was terminated due to signal 9
2022-02-24T12:26:47.009926+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:47 +0000] [282] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 282
2022-02-24T12:26:48.611144+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.63.238 - - [24/Feb/2022:12:26:48 +0000] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Nyhiajz&sid=987213a56f574506a7fe38ec6a023e81 HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "https://newfacetrack.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"
2022-02-24T12:26:48.611974+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=client at=warning code=H27 desc="Client Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Nyhiajz&sid=987213a56f574506a7fe38ec6a023e81" host=newfacetrack.herokuapp.com request_id=ef81a1bf-da56-4bf0-9258-f8589af364bb fwd="27.57.153.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28603ms status=499 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-24T12:26:49.699755+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NyhiaeJ&sid=987213a56f574506a7fe38ec6a023e81" host=newfacetrack.herokuapp.com request_id=13ab5d74-ff0b-42c2-8327-bd40c0900da2 fwd="27.57.153.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-02-24T12:26:50.065428+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:50 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:242)
2022-02-24T12:26:50.067465+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:50 +0000] [242] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 242)
2022-02-24T12:26:51.080378+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:51 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 242 was terminated due to signal 9
2022-02-24T12:26:51.082532+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-02-24 12:26:51 +0000] [290] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 290
```

Comment: you cannot use any gui in you heroku python code, also you need the "headless" version from pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python code currently uses [`waitKey(0)`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.7/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey) but that doesn't make sense in this context. Nobody is sitting inside the data centre waiting to press a key on a keyboard for you.

Remove that from your code and I think you'll be good to go.